# Convert Deserialization method to Async

Tags: c#, serialization, asynchronous

I am trying to convert this method that deserializes an object into a string with Async/Await.

```
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                T theObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
                return theObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean Async/Await, or just any sort of asynchronous pattern?

Comment: I am looking for Async/Await Jeff, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most serialization APIs do not have `async` implementations, which means the only thing you can really do is *wrap* a sync method. For example:

```
public static Task<T> DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(string xml)
{
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer =
                new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            T theObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
            return Task.FromResult(theObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't *actually* async - it just meets the required API. If you have the option, using `ValueTask<T>` is preferable in scenarios where the result may often be synchronous/

Either way, you should then be able to do something like:

```
var obj = await DeserializeObject<YourType>(someXml);
Debug.WriteLine(obj.Name); // etc
```

without needing to know whether the actual implementation was synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Noted that the method is still sync because there is no "await" syntax for switching context. It's just a sync Task and meaningless for await it.

Comment: @shtse8 yes, that's a fair comment - I've clarified

Answer (score 2):

A little sample, pretty primitive way:

```
    public delegate T Async<T>(string xml);

    public void Start<T>()
    {
        string xml = "<Person/>";
        Async<T> asyncDeserialization = DeserializeObject<T>;
        asyncDeserialization.BeginInvoke(xml, Callback<T>, asyncDeserialization);
    }

    private void Callback<T>(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Async<T> dlg = (Async<T>)ar.AsyncState;
        T item = dlg.EndInvoke(ar);
    }

    public T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                T theObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
                return theObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

you define a delegate and using it to Begin/End invoke using callbacks.

using the next versions of C# you can use the async keyword to get your code run asynchronously.

Comment: Tamir, I am using the next version of C# in Windows8.  Could you give me an example using await and async?  That is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with a `string` as data source doing things async would only introduce more overhead and give you nothing for it.

But if you where reading from a stream you could copy from the source stream to a `MemoryStream`(buffering all data), then deserialize from the `MemoryStream`, that would increase the memory usage but would lower the amount of time you will block the thread.

Answer (score -5):

You can return

```
Task.FromResult(theObject)
```

Comment: This will run synchronously.