# The client is disconnected because the underlying request has been completed. There is no longer an HttpContext available

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We are intermittently getting a `The client is disconnected because the underlying request has been completed. There is no longer an HttpContext available` exception in our WebApi endpoint.

Does anyone know what is causing this error, or how it can be reproduced in a consistent way? Currently it happens in 150 out of 100,000 requests.

The exception is thrown by `XmlDeserialize()` in this part of the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Process()
{
    using (var requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyEntity));

        // !! The below line throws the exception
        MyEntity entity = serializer.Deserialize(requestStream) as MyEntity;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the full exception message:

```
  "ExceptionType": "HttpException",
  "Message": "The client is disconnected because the underlying request has been completed.  There is no longer an HttpContext available.",
  "StackTrace": [
    "HttpBufferlessInputStream.Read;0",
    "SeekableBufferedRequestStream.Read;0",
    "XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData;0",
    ...
```

---

**Edit:** I found this in the source code for .NET.
[System.Web.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/System.Web.txt):

```
HttpBufferlessInputStream_ClientDisconnected=The client is disconnected because the underlying request has been completed. There is no longer an HttpContext available.
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpBufferlessInputStream.cs,332ecbede7a1f12a:

```
// We are done if the count == 0 or there is no more content
while (count > 0 && _remainingBytes != 0) {
    // Do the actual read
    bytesRead = wr.ReadEntityBody(buffer, offset, count);
    if (bytesRead <= 0) {
        if (!_context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
            if (_persistEntityBody) {
                SetRawContentOnce();
            }
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString(SR.HttpBufferlessInputStream_ClientDisconnected));
```

So the exception is thrown by HttpBufferlessInputStream.Read(), after `wr.ReadEntityBody(buffer, offset, count)` returns 0 or negative, and  `_context.Response.IsClientConnected` is false.

This would mean that the client became disconnected while XmlDeserialize() was still running. But from my limited experiments with netcat, .NET waits until the entire XML request has been uploaded before even calling the controller method. So we aren't uploading the request while we are still deserializing.

Comment: Might be you can try to use async method to deserialize the object, something like out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883913/convert-deserialization-method-to-async

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. My crystal ball suggests you are using the http context from a `Task`.

Comment: @mjwills I updated the code with some more details (it shows the controller part, and from there it takes the stream as `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`. I am not sure whether I'm using the http context from a Task, I'll have to goodle to see what that means.

Comment: @mjwills, If you are still interested, I found more info about the error, from looking at the sources for .NET which microsoft has fortunately made public. There are more details in my update but in a nutshell, `_context.Response.IsClientConnected` becomes false while we are still deserializing..

Comment: If you remove the `using` does it work?

Comment: As the problem is not reproducible in our test environment, I cannot say. But those failing requests happen rarely (150 out of 100,000), so I think there is some kind of disconnect.

Comment: I don't really know if this matters, but per the example given by the docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8, they create the serializer outside of the using statement.

Comment: Stream processing is an issue in this case. Request stream which is a network stream has limited lifetime and could "dispose" any time. You should read content from stream ASAP and pass to deserializer retrieved data, not this stream.

Currently when you are processing bigger amount of data (that's why it's not consistent) stream is disposed/closed while deserialization is not completed.

Please read about request lifecycle in ASP.Net WebApi.

Comment: What happens if you close the browser tab while the request is being processed?

Comment: @MatJ There is no browser tab, the request comes from another component in the system. In any event, I've tried disconnecting the request but it doesn't reproduce this particular exception.

Comment: Unreliable connections then? Does the request originate on the same system or travels through a network? A request timeout in client component can close the connection right? Something happens 15 out of 10,000 times that your server takes some time to process the request and hangs for more than timeout period?

Answer (score 6):

Like it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357828/async-inside-using-block) you should avoid capturing the synchronization context and use `.ConfigureAwait(false);`

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Process()
{
    using (var requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyEntity));
        MyEntity entity = serializer.Deserialize(requestStream) as MyEntity;
    }
    ...
}
```

*As noticed by [Thowk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6015844/thowk), [SynchronizationContext has been removed from ASP.NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).*

Comment: It's worth to notice, that SynchronizationContext has been removed from ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thank you, but can you provide more detail on why this happens? From my understanding, the HttpContext of the request can't die until the request is completed, and that can't happen while we're in the Deserialize() method because obviously the parent hasn't returned yet.

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is not what you want here, since you need to capture the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think its empty data or execution timeout issue. Try to capture time and data  of event called and api call returned. Try some stress testing with console application.
Check your IIS or Web Server Logs.
Regarding your code its an async  method 
 add extra line

```
string str = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Write str to log and check what data was in it.
Try converting  it to sync method.

change your time out.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: From my experiments, it seems like .NET doesn't even begin the request until all the POST method's body has been uploaded. I tested that with netcat. So this really might be the solution. There is no point using an async method since the data is already there and there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: Please mark  this as partial answer or upvote it.Last time somebody downvote it as unwanted or incorrect answer.